# Read from character delimted file and assign into variables | ksh Unix shell

Tags: unix, ksh, delimiter, readfile, ifs

I am using ksh.

I need to read the data from file, into the variables and then further use them for sending emails.

- File can be delimited by any less used characters (like | ^ etc.) or group of characters.
- Need to retrieve **mail from, mail to,cc,bcc, subject, body** from file.
- I am spooling into file from table, thus delimiter can be any character, but less used in general english because characters like , & * etc. might be present in Body and that may return wrong value.

**File:** (***cc*** and **bcc** are not available in the file i.e they are blank)

```
na734@company.com|NA734@company.COM|||TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR|Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>

Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>
The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.
Regards,<br>
FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>

This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail
Reply to the following person for further details:
na734@company.com
```

**Code using:**

```
while IFS='|' read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
do 
flag1=`echo $a1`
flag2=`echo $a2`
flag3=`echo $a3`
flag4=`echo $a4`
flag5=`echo $a5`
flag6=`echo $a6`
done < $RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System`date +%y%m%d`.csv
```

**It is not setting the variables.**

And when using code below: It is showing undesired output:

```
while IFS='|' read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
do 
echo $a1
echo $a2
echo $a3
echo $a4
echo $a5
echo $a6
done < $RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System`date +%y%m%d`.csv
```

**Output:** (**Hell lot of blank lines**)

```
na734@company.com
NA734@company.COM


TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR
Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>






Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>





The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.





Regards,<br>





FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>











This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail





Reply to the following person for further details:





na734@company.com
```

Comment: Don't you just need to parse first line?

Comment: It is not just one line. Instead it is One Single Entry Only. And the problem is that, the last entry is BODY of email which is indeed having many lines in itself.

Comment: Could maybe use `cut` to assign each variable?  `cut -f1 -d '|'`  using f1 through f6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ksh, the last command in a pipeline is executed in the current shell.

I would process the first line, then append all the other lines to the `body` variable.

```
file="$RUNTIME/EMAIL_$System$(date +%y%m%d).csv"
sed 1q "$file" | IFS="|" read -r from to cc bcc subj body
body="$body
$(sed 1d "$file")"

printf "%s: %s\n" from "$from" to "$to" cc "$cc" bcc "$bcc" subj "$subj" body "$body"
```

```
from: na734@company.com
to: NA734@company.COM
cc:
bcc:
subj: TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR
body: Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>

Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>
The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.
Regards,<br>
FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>

This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail
Reply to the following person for further details:
na734@company.com
```

I sometimes like to use `sed` in place of `head/tail`

Comment: The only problem is in BODY only, and here it came again. All other fields are showing fine, but for body, it's showing this error `generate_error_file.ksh[174]: body+=$\n:  not found` .. PS: I'm new to shell, thus doesn't have that much knowledge of it.

Comment: Also, i found out some alternate solution being, to spool BODY separately in another file and then use it. In any case i will use that file directly as body in `mailx` command.

Comment: You may have an older ksh. I've updated the way the text is appended to the body variable

Answer (score 0):

I used the `cut` command and it seemed to work well assigning them to variables. Although, I am unsure if your file will have multiple entries in it.

**Testing.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

a1=$(cat test.txt | cut -f1 -d '|' -s)
a2=$(cat test.txt | cut -f2 -d '|' -s)
a3=$(cat test.txt | cut -f3 -d '|' -s)
a4=$(cat test.txt | cut -f4 -d '|' -s)
a5=$(cat test.txt | cut -f5 -d '|' -s)
a6=$(cat test.txt | cut -f6 -d '|')

echo $a1
echo $a2
echo $a3
echo $a4
echo $a5
echo $a6
```

**test.txt**

```
na734@company.com|NA734@company.COM|||TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR|Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br>

Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br>
The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file.
Regards,<br>
FIMS Web Application<br><br><br>

This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail
Reply to the following person for further details:
na734@company.com
```

**output:**

```
$Testing.sh
na734@company.com
NA734@company.COM


TEST EMAIL FOR LMS ERROR
Hi <<FIRST_NAME>>, <br><br> Following errors are generated during migration of LMS data into FIMS application.<br><br><br> The respective details of Error(s) occured is logged into the attached file. Regards,<br> FIMS Web Application<br><br><br> This is an auto-generated e-mail, please don't reply to this e-mail Reply to the following person for further details: na734@company.com
```